# Kotlin flow buffer capacity

Tags: kotlin

I have a question about Kotlin flow buffer capacity. The following code:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.*

suspend fun main() = coroutineScope {
    flow { 
        for (i in 1..3) { 
            println("Emiting $i")
            emit(i) 
        }
    }.buffer(0)
    .collect { 
        value -> 
            delay(100)
            println("Consuming $value")
    }
}
```

generates the following output:

```
Emiting 1
Emiting 2
Consuming 1
Emiting 3
Consuming 2
Consuming 3
```

If I remove the buffer, the result is:

```
Emiting 1
Consuming 1
Emiting 2
Consuming 2
Emiting 3
Consuming 3
```

Shall I assume that when the capacity is 0 means that is actually 1?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the capacity is actually 0. It just looks like you are buffering an element because the collect is first consuming an element, and then delays for 100ms. That allows the flow to emit another element in the meanwhile.

The `buffer` function actually creates a second coroutine that allows the `flow` and `collect` functions to execute concurrently. Without the call to `buffer`, each element must be done with the `collect` before `flow` can continue with the next element, because both functions are executed by the same coroutine.

Let's step through your code to figure out how it happens:

1. The flow delays for 1ms, prints `Emitting 1`, emits `1`, and suspends.
2. Collect immediately consumes `1`, then starts the delay for 100ms.
3. The flow continues because `1` was consumed, delays for another 1ms, prints `Emitting 2`, emits `2`, then suspends.
4. Collect finishes the delay of 100ms, prints `Consuming 1`, then consumes `2` and delays for another 100ms.
5. The flow continues because `2` was consumed, delays for another 1ms, prints `Emitting 3`, emits `3`, then suspends.
6. Collect finishes the delay of 100ms, prints `Consuming 2`, then consumes `3` and delays for another 100ms.
7. Collect finishes the delay of 100ms, prints `Consuming 3`, then finishes collecting.
8. The flow continues, and finishes because there's no more elements to emit.

You can read more about `buffer` here: https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/buffer.html

Comment: But if we remove the buffer the behaviour is different. The result is: Emiting 1
Consuming 1
Emiting 2
Consuming 2
Emiting 3
Consuming 3

Comment: @PedroAlipio The difference is when the element is regarded as consumed. With `buffer`, the element is consumed immediately when collect starts processing it. This allows the flow to continue while the collect is delaying. Without `buffer`, the element is not regarded as consumed until the collect has finished processing it.

Comment: @PedroAlipio So, `buffer` creates another coroutine for collecting the elements. Without `buffer`, the `flow` and `collect` is performed in the same coroutine and is therefore running sequentially. The `buffer` function allows the `flow` and `collect` to run concurrently.

Comment: I see, When it suspends in the first consumed element, the buffer operation, as it doesn't have any capacity, instead of waiting for the consumer to finish, it requests a new element right away. Not quite what I was expecting but it makes sense since it doesn't require to store the next element because it suspends and waits for the consumer ar that point. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Not really, it's 0. The `buffer(0)` method uses a channel under the hood, and size 0 effectively makes the channel an `unbuffered channel`. The flow and consumer both need to be ready to emit/consume:

> Unbuffered channels transfer elements when sender and receiver meet each other (aka rendezvous). [buffered-channels](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/channels.html#buffered-channels)

- Flow prints **"Emiting 1"**
- Flow tries to emit 1 and suspends (no buffer, nor reader awaiting)
- Collector is ready for reading. Flow emits 1, collector reads 1.
- Collector suspends on `delay 100`
- Flow prints **"Emiting 2"**
- Flow tries to emit 2 and suspends (no buffer, nor reader awaiting)
- Collector prints **"Consuming 1"**
- Collector is ready for reading. Flow emits 2, collector reads 2
- Collector suspends on `delay 100`
- Flow prints **"Emiting 3"**
- Flow tries to emit 3 and suspends (no buffer, nor reader awaiting)
- Collector prints **"Consuming 2"**
- Collector is ready for reading. Flow emits 3, collector reads 3
- Collector suspends on `delay 100`
- Flow exits
- Collector prints **"Consuming 3"** and exits

When you remove the `buffer(0)`, the situation is a bit different. there is no channel involved. The flow is a "cold-stream", i.e. it kind of waits for the consumer to pull next items:

- Collector "subscribes" to the Flow
- Flow prints **"Emiting 1"**, emits "1" and suspends
- Collector reads "1", suspends for 100ms and prints **"Consuming 1"**
- Collector asks for the next item
- Flow prints **"Emiting 2"**, emits "2" and suspends
- ...

Comment: But If we remove the buffer we get:

Emiting 1
Consuming 1
Emiting 2
Consuming 2
Emiting 3
Consuming 3

Is buffer(0) different from not having buffer?

Comment: When you remove the buffer, there are no channels involved anymore, so the mechanics are a bit different. Shortly speaking, the flow accepts back-pressure, so the items are kind of polled by the consumer.

Comment: Thanks, I was not understanding exactly when the producer was suspended. I see that it suspends when emitting the second element (and no need of storing any element in the buffer) since the first was already consumed (and suspended when collecting).